# How to refactor setState callback to useEffect with a parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have a callback function that uses a parameter from a parent function similar to this

```
this.state = {
  var: ''
}
const updateStuff = (index) => {
  this.setState({var: 'asdf'}, ()=>props.dispatch(updateOther(index))
}
```

I am trying to refactor it to use useEffect instead and got stuck with this.

```
const [var, setVar] = useState('');

const updateStuff = (index) => {
  setVar('asdf')
}

useEffect(() => {
  props.dispatch(updateOther(index))
}, [var])
```

I'm not sure how I can get useEffect to read index like how it did with the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `index` state, and set it as the dependency of the `useEffect`. In the callback also set the `index`.

In the `useEffect` check that the `index` is not the default value (`null` in the example), so it won't dispatch on mount.

```
const [var, setVar] = useState('');
const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);

const updateStuff = index => {
  setVar('asdf');
  setIndex(index);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (index !== null) props.dispatch(updateOther(index))
}, [index])
```